# Regex /\-\s/ doesn’t match div with dash as content

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, text

So, I have a `div` with just   `-` as text in it, and I want to remove it. Why is this not working?

```
    $('.p-infotext').each(function () {
        var elem = $(this);
        var thisText = $(this).text();
        if (thisText.match("/\-\s/")) {
            elem.remove();
            alert("it's working");
        }
    });
```

The `/\-\s/` match seems to work fine on the site RegExr. See the image:

[image]

Comment: can you provide a snippet?

Comment: I really don’t get why you’re trying to match `⁢  -` with `/\-\s/` instead of `\s\s\-`.

Comment: @barmar, yes, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two syntaxes (the `"` syntax and the `/` syntax). Also I don't think you want the `\s` (require a whitespace character afterwards). Try:

```
    if (thisText.match(/\-\b/)) {
```

**Updated** to account for false positives described in comment.

Comment: It works, but there is a problem: it match divs which contains words with a "-" in it, like "foo-bar". I want to match only divs which contain only a "-" write in it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

I used `/\s\s\-/` to match two whitespaces and then a `"-"`!

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.